# Any current workarounds to use Sonar for Java 7 code?

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd, java-7

I try to use Sonar on a Java 7 project (which relies on new syntactic features) and the PMD part and the Checkstyle part fail to parse those files.

The Findbugs part fails to read Java 7 class files.

*This causes Sonar to consider only 10% of my classes.*

Can there be a workaround for this?

**EDIT: [There is an issue for Java 7 compatibility](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2584).

Please vote for this issue, so it will be fixed soon.**

Comment: Can you not disable PMD rules?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, edited the question: everything else fails too. On source-files and class-files levels.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is going to be the case, until the upstream projects like PMD, Findbugs, Checkstyle et al can understand Java 7 syntax. Sonar has dependencies on these projects, so bugs like [these](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3327072&group_id=56262&atid=479921) have to be fixed first.

Comment: I confirm that Java7 will be fully supported in Sonar 2.12. Patches have been sent to Checkstyle and PMD teams. Findbugs already supports Java7.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make findbugs dev build manually and put it into sonar. Not the easiest way.

```
svn checkout http://findbugs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/findbugs
```